# Generate unique id for each block in jQuery templating

Tags: jquery, templating, jquery-templates

I am generating a set of DIV tags using jQuery tempalting (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) for the json data which i receive with ajax.

I want to assign uniqe ids to the dynamically generated div's for further action on them.

i tried something like

```
var i = 0;
$( "#myTemplate" ).tmpl( data ).attr('id',++i).appendTo( "#container" );
```

but the value of i never changed. it assigned id=0 for all the div tags.

Now i got it working by doing a .each() and setting id by incrementing 'i' on all the matching div tags which have a common class assigned but i wanted to do it in one go.

Any idea?

Comment: well i did not find any of the answers suitable, i made the id as part of the json itself and setting the id attribute also during the call to tmpl() any better solution welcome....

Answer (score 2):

I would go the other way - generate an id right in the template. Say, your template is:

```
<script id="divTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div id='${getNextId()'}></div>
    <div id='${getNextId()'}></div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = 1;
    function getNextId()
    {
        return ++id;
    }
</script>
```

That method will be called for every div, generating a new id in-place.

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();
var i = d.getTime();
```

I think this could be a better option, as its inc milliseconds

OR

```
$.each('/selector goes here/',function (i,n){
    $( "#myTemplate" ).tmpl( data ).attr('id',i).appendTo( "#container" ); 
});
```

Comment: well if u are on loop and it will generated a random id, and make it a unique id, more reliable

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in one go in the example you posted. Since your method would only be called once, it's value would only be incremented once. `.each` would be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Attr is not called for each item in the collection.

Rather atts uses the supplied values looping over the collection so i will not increase as you excpect.